# Make puts thread-safe

Tags: ruby, multithreading

I'm have a multithreaded program that prints to the console in hundreds of places. Unfortunately, instead of

```
Line 2
Line 1
Line 3
```

I get

```
Line2Line1

Line3
```

I am trying to make `puts` thread safe.

---

In Python (which I don't think has this problem, but suppose it did), I'd do

```
old_print = print

print_mutex = threading.Lock()

def print(*args, **kwargs):
    print_mutex.acquire()
    try:
        old_print(*args, **kwargs)
    finally:
        print_mutex.release()
```

I'm trying this in Ruby,

```
old_puts = puts

puts_mutex = Mutex.new

def puts(*args)
    puts_mutex.synchronize {
        old_puts(*args)
    }
```

But this doesn't work: "undefined method `old_puts`"

---

How can I make thread-safe (i.e. not print partial lines)?

Comment: Tip: when you do `old_puts = puts` you are implicitly doing `old_puts = puts()`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
alias old_puts puts
```

or more modern way:

```
module MyKernel
  PutsMutex = Mutex.new
  def puts(*)
    PutsMutex.synchronize{super}
  end
end

module Kernel
  prepend MyKernel
end
```

Answer (score 1):

The reason for this behaviour is that `puts` internally calls the underlying `write` function twice - one for the actual value to be written, and one for the newline to be written. (Explained in [Ruby's puts is not atomic](https://medium.com/@RohitPaulK/rubys-puts-is-not-atomic-889c57fc9a28))

Here's a hack to make `puts` call `write` exactly once: Append `\n` to the string you're writing. Here's what this looks like in my code:

```
# Threadsafe `puts` that outputs text and newline atomically
def safe_puts(msg)
    puts msg + "\n"
end
```

`puts` internally checks whether the object being written has a newline at the end, and only calls `write` again if that isn't true. Since we've changed the input to end with a newline, `puts` ends up making only one call to `write`.

Comment: Does this mean that if you use `print` instead of `puts`, and include the newline as part of the string passed to `print`, you would not need the `safe_puts`?

Comment: Also, for me, what I really need is a way to print multiple lines in 1 atomic operation. I guess I'd need to do the same as I suggested before, building the multiline string myself, and then passing it to `print`?

Comment: Yes, and yes :)